# updating second level nested object inside array of objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
Below is my JSON and I want to update the title:'second title' to title:'new title' inside videos array in the below JSON.

{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "username" : "test",
    "playlists" : [
        {
            "name" : "abc",         
            "videos" : [
                {
                    "title" : "first title"
                    "desc" : "first description",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "second title"
                    "desc" : "second description",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "def",         
            "videos" : [
                {
                    "title" : "third title"
                    "desc" : "third description",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "fourth title"
                    "desc" : "fourth description",
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

How will I do that?I tried below query but no luck.It always updates only the first object inside videos

```
db.xyz.update(
{ username: 'test','playlists.videos.title' : 'second title' }, 
{ $set:{'playlists.0.videos.$.title' : "new title" }}
);
```

If I replace $ with 0 and 1 i could achieve what I want but I don't have the positional key/index as it can be anywhere.
I cannot restructure it as my data is already in this format.

Comment: The best solution is don't nest the arrays in the first place. This is very easily done in your case. Instead of putting `videos` arrays inside a `playlists` array, simply make the document array `videos` and include a `"playlist"` property on every "video" document. See the [positional `$` operator documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which explains why nested array updates cannot work.

Comment: i have name and similar such keys eg JCnumber,Startdate,enddate etc in playlist which is been added using a different form and videos are added using different form, hence your solution wont work! Do you have any other suggestion other than changing the json?

Comment: Hey. I'm just telling you what **will** work, because that is how MongoDB is designed. If you nest one array within another, then positional matching on arrays **will not work**. It really is as simple as that. Using absolute indexes **BAD**. Replacing entire array structures **BAD**. Sooner or later you need to "bite the bullet" and realize that nesting arrays is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Currently, multiple positional operator matching doesnot work for nested arrays - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831. So, you cannot invoke `playlists.$.videos.$.title` . For now, i think the best way is to modify your data from application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nested array document cannot be done using positional operator, since it is a [limitation of mongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831).

> But this can be done using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) of aggregation
>   pipeline

Approach:

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - Used to unwind our arrays, it is used twice since we have two arrays.

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - Project the document with the update which we want to do

[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) - Use condition together with project in aggregation pipeline to add the desired result to the output

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - Once we projected our desired result, we need to put it back into the original document format.

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) - Use push to add the array format

We had two nested arrays in our document and now we have unwinded it, so to get back the original document we need to use $group and $push together two times.
First we need to group and push the inner array and then the outer array.

[$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) - Finally use this to write the output to a collection. Here we can give the same name of the collection to overwrite it with the new results.

Mongo Shell Query to get the desired result

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$playlists"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$playlists.videos"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "username": 1,
      "playlists.name": 1,
      "playlists.videos.desc": 1,
      "playlistsvideostitle": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$playlists.videos.title",
              "second title"
            ]
          },
          then: "My New title",
          else: "$playlists.videos.title"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "username": "$username",
        "playlistname": "$playlists.name"
      },
      "videos": {
        $push: {
          "title": "$playlistsvideostitle",
          "desc": "$playlists.videos.desc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      "username": {$first: "$_id.username"},
      "playlists": {
        $push: {
          "name": "$_id.playlistname",
          "videos": "$videos"
        }
      }
    }
  },
 {$out:"mycollection"}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

With mongo 3.6, you can use

```
db.xyz.update(
{"username": "test"},
{$set: {"playlists.$[i].videos.$[j].title": "new title"},
{arrayFilters: [{"i.name": "abc"}, {"j.title": "second title"}]
});
```